# Are there any other by default lazily evaluated languages apart from Haskell and Miranda?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, miranda

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#Implementation) only Haskell and Miranda are mentioned.

I am not sure about [elm](http://www.elm-lang.org).

Some other languages make it especially easy to declare a function to be computed lazily.

Are there programming languages where you have a global switch, say for a module or script file to be evaluated lazily?

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/lazy/

Comment: http://www.curry-language.org/ might qualify, and certainly https://github.com/Frege/frege does. Both are Haskell-inspired in a way, though.

Comment: [Clean](http://wiki.clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean).

Comment: R is lazzy too. (also the title of your question doesn't correspond to your actual question).

Comment: Shells, partially. Pipes only consume what's necessary.

Comment: [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php).

Comment: I think **all those comments are valid answers**, but I can only mark one as answer. So I don't really know what I should do. Any suggestions how to modify it?

Comment: And all those comments are really useful. So hopefully there will be more valuable comments.